# Why pass information in an Intent to a Fragment rather then getting it from the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-sqlite

I got an assignment to create an application. At the Splash screen stage, it is instructed to get a list from SQLite while in a Splash screen, and pass it to a Fragment (I did so by using an Intent).

My question is why not get it from the Fragment rather than passing it from the Splash screen to the Main Activity, and from there to the Fragment? It may seem unnecessary if it wasn't for some reason that's unknown to me.

When looking for information on this question I couldn't find anything. I guess it didn't come up previously, or at least I couldn't find the phrasing that was previously used.

The method that gets the list and passes it to the MainActivity:

```
private void toMainActivity(ArrayList<Movie> moviesList) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("moviesList", moviesList);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }
```

At MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Movie> moviesList = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("moviesList");
    Bundle listBundle = new Bundle();
    listBundle.putParcelableArrayList("moviesList", moviesList);

    Fragment mlf = new MoviesListFragment();
    mlf.setArguments(listBundle);
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragments_container, mlf);

    ft.commit();
}
```

At the Fragment:

```
Bundle listBundle = getArguments();
if (listBundle != null) {
    moviesList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("moviesList");
    moviesAdapter.attachMoviesList(moviesList);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be clear if you can post your current code.

Comment: It's probably because that's what the assignment is about. Perhaps ask whoever gave you the assignment.

Comment: That's an assignment for a job interview, so I prefer comin up with the answers rather than asking.

Comment: Added some relevant code.

Comment: You can get the list from SQLite from anywhere that you access context, so you can get it from fragments.

Comment: @AmirHossein That's ture, but I was instructed not to do that, so I guessed there's a reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

That's usually a matter of making sure you're working on the same instance of something. When passing something in a `Bundle` you're securing that the next screen will work on the same instance of the passed data that the previous screen was.

Whether it's better or worse than querying a db every time is a case-by-case thing. Sometimes you want to maintain data "continuity" between screens and sometimes you want to get the newest copy of the data (which could've been modified asynchronously).